# Java: Using ConcurrentHashMap as a lock manager

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, locking, concurrenthashmap

I'm writing a highly concurrent application, needing access to a large fine-grained set of shared resources. I'm currently writing a global lock manager to organize this. I'm wondering if I can piggyback off the standard `ConcurrentHashMap` and use that to handle the locking? I'm thinking of a system like the following:

- A single global `ConcurrentHashMap` object contains a mapping between the unique string id of the resource, and a <del>lock protecting that resource</del> unique id of the thread using the resource
- Tune the concurrency factor to reflect the need for a high level of concurrency
- Locks are acquired using the atomic conditional `replace(K key, V oldValue, V newValue)` method in the hashmap
- To prevent lock contention when locking multiple resources, locks must be acquired in alphabetical order

Are there any major issues with the setup? How will the performance be?

I know this is probably going to be much slower and more memory-heavy than a properly written locking system, but I'd rather not spend days trying to write my own, especially given that I probably won't be able to match Java's professionally-written concurrency code implementing the map.

<s>Also, I've never used ConcurrentHashMap in a high-load situation, so I'm interested in the following:</s>

- How well will this scale to large numbers of elements? (I'm looking at ~1,000,000 being a good cap. If I reach beyond that I'd be willing to rewrite this more efficiently)
- The documentation states that re-sizing is "relatively" slow. Just how slow is it? I'll probably have to re-size the map once every minute or so. Is this going to be problematic with the size of map I'm looking at?

Edit: Thanks Holger for pointing out that HashMaps shouldn't have that big of an issue with scaling

Also, is there is a better/more standard method out there? I can't find any places where a system like this is used, so I'm guessing that either I'm not seeing a major flaw, or theres something else.

---

Edit:

The application I'm writing is a network service, handling a variable number of requests. I'm using the Grizzly project to balance the requests among multiple threads.
Each request uses a small number of the shared resources (~30), so in general, I do not expect a large great deal of contention. The requests usually finish working with the resources in under 500ms. Thus, I'd be fine with a bit of blocking/continuous polling, as the requests aren't extremely time-sensitive and contention should be minimal.

In general, seeing that a proper solution would be quite similar to how `ConcurrentHashMap` works behind the scenes, I'm wondering if I can safely use that as a shortcut instead of writing/debugging/testing my own version.

Comment: I just found out about `Striped` in Google Guava, and it was everything I ever wanted.

Comment: Striped might be still memory intense. See my journey here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39675003/194609

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The re-sizing issue is not relevant as you already told an estimate of the number of elements in your question. So you can give a `ConcurrentHashMap` an initial capacity large enough to avoid any rehashing.

The performance will not depend on the number of elements, that’s the main goal of hashing, but the number of concurrent threads.

The main problem is that you don’t have a plan of how to handle failed locks. Unless you want to poll until locking succeeds (which is not recommended) you need a way of putting a thread to sleep which implies that the thread currently owning the lock has to wake up a sleeping thread on release if one exists. So you end up requiring conventional `Lock` features a `ConcurrentHashMap` does not offer.

Creating a `Lock` per element (as you said ~1,000,000) would not be a solution.

---

A solution would look a bit like the `ConcurrentHashMap` works internally. Given a certain concurrency level, i.e. the number of threads you might have (rounded up), you create that number of `Lock`s (which would be a far smaller number than 1,000,000).

Now you assign each element one of the `Lock`s. A simple assignment would be based on the element’s `hashCode`,  assuming it is stable. Then locking an element means locking the assigned `Lock` which gives you up to the configured concurrency level if all currently locked elements are mapped to different `Lock`s.

This might imply that threads locking different elements block each other if the elements are mapped to the same `Lock`, but with a predictable likelihood. You can try fine-tuning the concurrency level (as said, use a number higher than the number of threads) to find the best trade-off.

A big advantage of this approach is that you do not need to maintain a data structure that depends on the number of elements. Afaik, the new parallel `ClassLoader` uses a similar technique.

Comment: I edited my post with a bit more information about the problem. Regarding your solution: I realize I should have clarified when I said that there will be a mapping between the resource id and a lock. I wasn't referring to an actual `Lock` object, but simply an identifier of the thread using the resource, probably just the unique Thread.getID number. Thus, there shouldn't be 1,000,000 `Lock` objects created, just a couple of `Long`s. 

Thanks for your suggestions. I'll wait a day or two more to see if anything else comes up, otherwise I'll mark this as answer.

Comment: @RandomBK: I didn’t assume that you were referring to actual `Lock`s. I explained that you can’t do without `Lock`s as you need some sort of waiting queue for the case that an `acquire` fails when two threads try to lock the same element. `ConcurrentHashMap` does not provide this and regardless of how you would solve this issue, having a million waiting queues would not be sufficient. This is were my proposal jumps in. Using existing `Lock`s for maintaining the state and the waiting queue. But not a million.

Comment: Regarding your updated question: if polling is ok, you can use your hash map approach but you can simplify it: there is no reason to remember unlocked elements. So you can use `putIfAbsent` and `remove` to control the locking state. Then the map will only have the size equal to the number of *locked* elements which will be much smaller than the total number of elements.